# #if /#endif preprocessing directives

Tags: c++, c, preprocessor-directive

Should I always use `#if` directive coupled with `#endif`?

1. If yes - what could be a problem if I only use `#if`?
2. If no - when I use only `#if`, and when combination `#if`/`#else`?

Thank you.

Comment: `#if`and `#endif` aren't macros but preprocessing directives.

Comment: I can't imagine why you think this is an issue. Have you ever encountered a situation where omitting `#endif` looked like it would come in handy?

Comment: Also, I don't understand your second question. Did you mean "when" instead of "why"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1.If yes - what could be a problem if I only use #if?
```

As mentioned by others if you use only #if and don't match it with a #endif, the preprocessor will fail and it will shown as a compiler error.

```
2.If no - why I use only #if,and when combination #if/#else?
```

Even in case of #if/#else, there should be an #endif at the end. Otherwise it will not work. You can try it yourself and check.

These are most commonly used for conditional compilation, apart from checking and defining macros. Please find some relevant links (basic level) below:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor
http://www.phanderson.com/C/preprocess.html

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a matching `#endif`, (or `#else` ... `#endif`) your code will fail to compile.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Without the `#endif` the preprocessor will not come to know the end of the `#if` block.